# Alterar cor célula repeater

Tags: c#, css, asp.net, webforms

Estou fazendo um sistema `ASPNET c# WEBFORM`, e alimento um `REPEATER` com informações que vem do banco de dados.

Gostaria que determinada célula ficasse com determinada cor, conforme informação que vem do banco de dados.

Exemplo: Coluna `CodStatus`, se for **aprovado**, a célula fica verde e se for **reprovado** a célula fica vermelha.

Segue o código:

> ListarProposta.aspx

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptProposta" runat="server">
    <HeaderTemplate>      
        <table id="tblCustomers" class="footable" border="0"  >
            <thead>         
                <tr>
                    <th data-class="expand">
                        <font ><b>Código</b></font>
                    </th>
                    <th data-class="expand">
                        <font ><b>Situação </b></font>
                    </th>
                     <th scope="col">
                        <font ><b>Cliente</b></font>
                    </th>
                    <th style="display: table-cell;" data-hide="phone">
                        <font ><b>Valor Proposta</b></font>
                    </th>
                   <th class="text-center"   style="display: table-cell;" data-hide="phone">
                            <font ><b>Ação</b></font>
                   </th>
              </tr>
           </thead>
    </HeaderTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
        <tr style="color:red">
           <td >
                 <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "codproposta") %>   
           </td>
           <td>
                 <%#  DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "situacao") %>   
           </td>
            <td>
                 <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "cliente") %>   
           </td>
            <td>
                 <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "valortotal") %>   
           </td>
           <td>   
                <asp:ImageButton ID="imbtnAlterar" ImageUrl="~/img/editar.ico"  Width="30px" Height="30px" runat="server" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("codproposta") %>' />    
                <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/img/excluir.ico" Width="30px" Height="30px" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("codproposta")  %>'   /> 
           </td>
        </tr>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <FooterTemplate>      
    </table>              
    </FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

A maneira que carrego o `REPEATER`

> ListarProposta.aspx.cs

```
protected void CarregarProposta()
{
    Proposta p = new Proposta();
    p.codproposta = 0;
    SqlDataReader drProposta = p.ListarProposta(p);
    rptProposta.DataSource = drProposta;
    rptProposta.DataBind();

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para colocar uma cor na célula é só codificar uma linha comparando o resultado de cada item carregado se o valor daquele campo é um ou outro, exemplo minimo:

- Css

  ```
  <style>
    .aprovado {
      background-color: green;
    }
    .reprovado {
      background-color: red;
    }
  </style>
  ```

e a partir de `css` colocar isso na hora da criação do no `<ItemTemplate>`:

```
<table>
    <asp:Repeater ID="RptLista" runat="server">
    <HeaderTemplate>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Código</th>
          <th>Nome</th>
          <th>Status</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Codigo") %></td>
          <td><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Nome") %></td>
          <td class="<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Status")%>">
            <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Status") %>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
</table>
```

ou seja, essa é a linha da sua pergunta:

```
<td class="<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Status")%>">
```

onde essa escolha das duas classes criadas para `.aprovado` e `.reprovado` determinado no valor do retorno contido na lista enviada.

- Exemplo

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Eu ia postar quase exatamente a mesma coisa, só tinha criado os estilos como .aprovado e .reprovado... assim não precisaria nem do if no Bind 

Comment: Entendi a sua ideia realmente é boa mesmo, não tinha pensando nisso @LeandroAngelo

Comment: @LeandroAngelo fiz a alteração.

Comment: Muito obrigado. Era exatamente isto que eu queria. Funcionou corretamente.